# vSphere 5.1 authentication via external OpenLDAP

Tags: authentication, vmware, openldap, vsphere

I try to add OpenLdap authentication option to vSphere. I would like to give some users possibility to log in to vSphere using ldap accounts. So far I didn't found nothing. All tutorial in internet are for microsoft AD.
So Im doing this:

First login to vSphere-client using admin@SYSTEM-DOMAIN, select Sign-On and Discovery -> Configuration -> Add Identity Source

After that I provide all basic info:

name: ldap test

primary server URL: ldap://ldap:389

base DN for users: dc=ldap,dc=my_domain_here,dc=com

When I click "test connection" Im getting this:

```
"probing for connectivity faild"
```

There is no problem with LDAP because I added LDAP auth to many other services, I just can't do that auth for vCenter.

Maybe I dont understand the purpose of this feature in vSphere and maybe it's not possible to use user account from openLDAP to auth.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the official ducumentation at [Add a vCenter Single Sign On Identity Source](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-B23B1360-8838-4FF2-B074-71643C4CB040.html).

Did you add a service account user that can access your OpenLdap directory?

Comment: But I chose authentication type: anonymous. Im always doing that because it needs only read rights (I think). Anyway I changed authentication type and added user with password as you said. After that I have different error: "LDAP: error code: 34 - Invalid DN" but Im sure DN for users is correct.

Comment: Hey I just found out that user name have to be write in this form: cn=user_name,ou=group,dc=ldap,dc=my_domain_here,dc=com and then it works. Weird thing is I can't use it anonymously but well at least it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what worked for me is: "uid=root,cn=users,dc=your_domain,dc=com"

I'm using vCenter 5.5 Build 1624811 + Directory Server (openLDAP server) from Synology